# Set MKPinAnnotationView's image via url

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, mapkit

Is it possible to programmatically set the image for an MKPinAnnotationView based on URL? So far I have this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
static NSString *identifier = @"infl8Node";

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[infl8Node class]]) {
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"invisible.png"];
    annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;

    //Add image from url
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/downloads/arrest.png"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [annotationView addSubview:imgView];

    return annotationView;
}
return nil;
}
```

However it results in something like this:
[image: img on pin]

Has anyone done this or have a good idea as to how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `MKAnnotationView` instead of `MKPinAnnotationView`. Replace it

```
 annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        replace use MKAnnotationView here
```

**EDIT** : One Solution is use `custom` `animation`.

Refer [MKAnnotationView Animation example](https://gist.github.com/2399387)  an example of how I drop my MKAnnotationViews using custom animation.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do this and still use the drop animation?

Comment: Quick question, in that new code, where do you set the BOOL val back to YES?